# Filtering by the attribute of an associated model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following line in a view, which outputs the english description for a film:

```
@film.descriptions.where(language_id: 38)
```

Is there a way to write this that doesn't rely on knowing the language record's ID? I've been searching but haven't figured it out on my own yet. In this case the english description happens to have an ID of 38, though I'd rather not hard code the ID.

There's a Film model which has_many Descriptions, and Description belongs_to Language. The Language model has a 'code' attribute (en, de, etc), and it seems it would be cleaner to look up the film's description using the language's code rather than the model ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite as following:

```
Description.joins(:language)
  .where(film_id: @film, languages: {code: "en"})
```

Comment: Excellent! While @Alfie's solution works as well, I like that this solution remains a simple self contained activerecord query, which is ultimately what I was hoping for. I can use this pattern elsewhere in my app, other than the view. The final version I went with, since I already have the film object in scope:
`@film.descriptions.joins(:language).where(languages: { code: "en" })`

Comment: Oh, great. It's even a little shorter and works too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Write a helper method for `film` model like

```
def language(code)
   Language.where(code:code).first.id
end
```

And get film description as:

```
@film.descriptions.where(language_id: language('en'))
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. While I ended up using the other technique, this opened my eyes more to the possibilities of helper methods.

Comment: You can call this as the rails way of doing things. Using helper methods in various cases brings more meaning and readability to you code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by following way

```
@film.descriptions.joins(:language).where(language: {code: "en"})
```

It will return the flims with description language has "en" code

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't quite work. This was about as far as I got before asking, but kept getting errors in the query. The missing ingredients were the use of `joins(:language)` as well as "languages" (plural database table name) as the key in the where clause.